# how i grep for certain log lines

Tags: bash, grep, debian, rsyslog

I have the following logs (removed unnecessary info) :

```
Feb 18 11:38:54 Kingston dhcpd: DHCPACK
Feb 18 11:39:01 duxbury /USR/SBIN/CRON[27892]:
Feb 18 17:39:01 ruby /USR/SBIN/CRON[13080]:
```

How Can I grep for a server name (kingston, ruby or duxbury) while ensuring that date/time info is next to the server name? so for instance I could grep for kingston, and it would return "Feb 18 11:38:54 Kingston dhcpd: DHCPACK" but if only "some data Kingston" (no date/time info) was available, then nothing would be returned. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -E "^[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ Kingston"
```

Comment: This should either use `egrep ...` or `grep -E ...`.